# Bmesh.calc_tangent_edge_pair - how does it work?

Tags: python, bmesh

I'm trying to understand how bmesh.calc_tangent_edge_pairs works so I can replicate it in another software. I have looked at (what I believe) is the [source code](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/47451af027e247b82a5e990393c4101a0178bbdc/source/blender/bmesh/intern/bmesh_polygon.c#L349), but to be honest it didn't help much as I only know python.

Can anyone help me with an explanation how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do seem to have found the correct C code.

*Qualitative* answer: the code locates the two edges of the face that are going to give it the best answer and then uses them to calculate the normal by subtracting one vertex of an edge from the opposing vertex of the  other eged; adding the results of the two subtractions together and returning the normalized value.

It assumes that the best answer will come by using the pair of *opposing* edges that  together are the longest pair.  Since triangles don't have opposing edges in this sense it averages two of the edges and uses the average with the other edge.

Finally, it makes an adjustment in the rare degenerate case of an N-gon where the two best edges aren't opposing.

*Coding* answer:
The code in question, roughly does this:

- If the face is a tri, calculate the average of two of its faces and subtract that from the other edge to create the tangent.  Returns the normalized version of that calculation. Let $E_n$ be an  one edge then return $$normalize(E_3 - midpoint(E_1,E_2))$$
- If the face is a quad, it divides the edges into two *opposing* pairs.  For each pair it generates a vector by subtracting the endpoints of the edges.  Let $P_{n,m}$ be an endpoint then:
  $$V = P_{1,0} - P_{0,1}$$

  Doing this for two edges gives $V_a$ and $V_b$.  From this a tangent is calculated. Let $T$ = the tangent then
  $$T = V_a - V_b$$

  It does this for both pairs of opposing edges given $T_a$ and $T_b$.  It uses the largest of the two as the result.
- It does something similar for Ngons. The precise details are left as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marty! In my case I only need to care about quads.

Do you mean something like this in pseudo code?

```sub1 = edge1_vert1 - edge1_vert2;
sub2 = edge2_vert1 - edge2_vert2;
result = normalize(sub1+sub2)```

Comment: @SimonBjörk  Yes I do.  If this works for you, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: I think I'm missing something, can you have a look at the code below?

Answer (score 0):

Follow @Marty Fouts suggestion, but I'm not having any luck.

EDIT: Seems like this works. I just had to use e1_v1 to e2_v2 and e2_v1 to e1_v2.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

scene = bpy.context.scene

obj = scene.objects.get("Plane")
me = obj.data

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)

bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()

edge1 = bm.edges[0]
edge2 = bm.edges[2]

e1_v1, e1_v2 = edge1.verts
e2_v1, e2_v2 = edge2.verts

calc1 = e1_v2.co - e2_v1.co
calc2 = e2_v2.co - e1_v1.co

t = calc1-calc2

print(t)

t2 = bm.faces[0].calc_tangent_edge_pair()

print(t2)
```

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.  I've updated my answer to get the nomenclature right.